# How to convert Uint8List to Image Data Type

Tags: flutter, dart

The below code is converting png image to Image DataType but it is not converting SVG image to Image DataType.

```dart
var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(img.buffer.asUint8List()); // This is not working for SVG images.
```

Getting error:-

```dart
E/FlutterJNI( 9122): Failed to decode image
E/FlutterJNI( 9122): android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.nCreate(Native Method)
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.access$200(ImageDecoder.java:173)
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder$ByteBufferSource.createImageDecoder(ImageDecoder.java:250)
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmapImpl(ImageDecoder.java:1862)
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at android.graphics.ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.java:1855)
E/FlutterJNI( 9122):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.decodeImage(FlutterJNI.java:431)
I/flutter ( 9122): Exception: Invalid image data
```

Comment: I am not sure, but i think you need a package like https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg to handle svg images in flutter.

Comment: I think that package is used only to render svg's that's it...it wont convert Unit8List into Image datatype

Answer (score 0):

SVGs aren't supported in the `Image` class. Use `flutter_svg` and then pass your `Uint8List` to `SvgPicture.memory(yourUint8List)`